# What file should I put for installation of .sty file

Tags: packages

The following procedure is correct ?

**1)** The following error occured:

```
  `! LaTeX Error: File "baskervillef.sty" not found.`
```

**2)** I try to install `baskervillef.sty'. To do so, I use the page:

```
     https://ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/baskervillef
```

**3)** I downloaded it, i.e. `baskervillef.zip`, in which the following files exits:

1. doc
2. enc
3. map
4. opentype
5. tex
6. tfm
7. type1
8. vf
9. README

**4)** I open the file `tex` then I found the file `baskervillef.sty` in the file `tex`

**5)** I put **only** one file `baskervillef.sty` in the  path`C:\texlive\texmf-local\tex\baskervillef.sty`. **I ignore all download files** (described in **2)** ) except `baskervillef.sty`. I am not sure, is it OK?

**6)** Execute the code `mktexlsr` on the command prompt to reflect the change of adding the style file.

---

Edit for comments

1. I executed the code `kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFLOCAL` on command prompt, and  its return is `C:/texlive/texmf-local`
2. So, I download the file  `baskervillef.tds` which contains three directory, i.e.,   **doc**, **font** , **tex**.
3. I put these three things `doc, font, tex`(including 638 files and 25 folders ) to the path `C:/texlive/texmf-local` which is the return of the  `kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFLOCAL` .
4. Execute the code `mktexlsr` for reflecting above changes.

---

Comment: Since baskervillef is already in texlive you should have it already. Is your texlive up to date? Nowadays there is hardly any reason to install packages by hand

Comment: Thank you for your reply @daleif.  I am not sure that the `baskervillef.sty` is already contains my texlive. If already it is contained, then why the error occured ? `! LaTeX Error: File "baskervillef.sty" not found.`

Comment: Which page are used to install the texlive ? I know such page at least one, but my unstable wifi cannot succeed tex installation.

Comment: Try to start with the minimal or infrastructure-only scheme and then install the rest of TeX Live if your connection has problems.

Comment: And no, it is not okay to ignore the other folders. Just put the whole thing into one folder that you specify as auxiliary TeX tree.

Comment: It is *not* enough to copy various files to their correct destinations; one also has to update the filename database of the TeX distribution. Anyway, what  do you get if you type `kpsewhich baskervillef.sty` at a command prompt? Do you get `/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/baskervillef/baskervillef.sty` as the response, or do you get a blank, i.e., empty response? Incidentally, in my TeX installation, the folder `/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/baskervillef` contains 26 files, only one of which is `baskervillef.sty`.

Comment: Thank you @TeXnician, I have putted the all unpacked files from `baskervillef.zip` in the path `C:\texlive\texmf-local\tex\inconsolata`

Comment: Why into `tex\inconsolata`? You have to match the directory structure. So what's in the `doc` folder will go into the `texmf-local\doc` folder and so on. Afterwards, recreate the file name database and you are good to go.

Comment: Thank you @Mico. I know the code `kpsewhich name.sty` and I execute the code `kpsewhich baskervillef.sty`, then the return is the path of the style file `baskervillef.sty` as follows: `c:/texlive/texmf-local/tex/baskervillef.sty`

Comment: I am sorry @TeXnician,  its only my type miss. I correctly put the unpacked files in the path `C:\texlive\texmf-local\tex\baskervillef`

Comment: That's still not the correct TeX directory structure but with some luck it might work. Usually, the extracted content of the doc folder should go into `texmf-local\doc`, the extracted content of the tex folder into `texmf-local\tex` and so on.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know @TeXnician. But, in my tex `doc` does not exist in the `C:\texlive\texmf-local\tex`. Is it OK to create `doc` by hands such that `C:\texlive\texmf-local\tex\doc` ?

Comment: It would be okay, but unnecessary, because as I have written above you should follow TDS and therefore create `texmf-local\doc` etc.

Comment: What exactly did you install? Full scheme or a smaller one. Use the tlmgr command line tool

Answer (score 2):

You should ALWAYS do your best to use the package manager to install any missing package since it should know where to put in this case **638 Files (600 of those are the fonts) and 25 Folders** specifically for your specific modifications to the distro.

If you must manually download **look for the TDS zip** in this case it is http://mirrors.ctan.org/install/fonts/baskervillef.tds.zip this file is TDS COMPLIANT that means you only need to unpack it in exactly the right location and it will be similar to the one downloaded by the package manager

I understand in your case you are off-line and cannot download as and when required, however I would strongly suggest you look at the possibility of downloading a full set of files to a single location (4 to 8 GB usb) such that your Tex Live package manager can use the local set when you need them. This is often done in a similar fashion to a network install where single users can call on a local repository. That would be simpler that frequently downloading single packages. One alternative is to obtain the Tex Live Annual (April) DVD and just update those parts of your system when needed.

I do not know if you may find W32TeX more suitable for your needs and both it's [abTexinst](http://www.math.sci.hokudai.ac.jp/~abenori/soft/abtexinst.html) package manager or the Standard Tex Live Setup manager can allow you to select and/or update large groups of packages without having to download the full collection. Just be careful not to mix them or else you could get version conflicts since W32TeX is now in 2019 release whilst TeX Live is still at 2018. IF you keep the packages on a usb stick with the manager you can then take it on-line to check for partial updates.

---

Back to your current issue

**Beware the next step** can replace an up-to-date set of files with an older version which is why you should use the package manager that will do most version checking.

**For TeX Live** you need to check where your texmf-local folder is by running
`kpsewhich --var-value TEXMFLOCAL`
If that returns nothing then you need to build AND SET one

When you unpack that TDS.zip you will see just 3 of the 25 folders (Doc Fonts and Tex) You **very simply need to copy or move those 3 folders to your texmf-local** folder and accept ALL overwrites necessary to replace any of the 638 files you may already have, this is necessary to keep all the new files at the same version.

**MOST IMPORTANTLY**
You have now compromised your fonts and filename database (more than 1200 times) so need to tell the package manager what you have done and ask it to Update filename database (600+ ways) and Update fonts mapping tables (600 ways)

**For Tex Live** to update filename database you need to yet again run **`mktexlsr` or `texhash`**
for MiKTeX users its `initexmf --update-fndb`

Then for font mappings read and apply the following instructions

4. Font map files: telling TeX Live about the new font here https://www.tug.org/fonts/fontinstall.html
   NOTE where it says *newfont*.map in this case that is
   **`updmap-sys --force --enable Map=BaskervilleF.map`**

Comment: I try to install from `https://www.ms.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~abenori/soft/abtexinst.html` But error occurs. I buy a book with DVD which contains the same installer. I copy and paste from DVD to USB and using this copy, I have installed my tex. But this installation does not have any fundamental style files.

Comment: The abexinst is a manager of W32tex  which is a slightly different version compared the standard TeX Live is most useful if your full tex installation will be based on all its packages otherwise it is not good to mix the two versions as there could be issues between the versions of components. If that is what you are using it helps to mention W32TeX if relevant to questions. So now understand why this may be one of those. I do not use abtexinst well as I do not read cjk so can not say which fonts are included but you are right that it does not show individual fonts. so use the .TDS.zip file